# Putting tikzpicture and align environment side by side

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, align, minipage

I would like to put a tikzpicture and an align environment side by side within a figure using minipages. However they are not at the same height.
Here is my example code

```
\documentclass[11pt,leqno]{scrreprt} 
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h] 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.2\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[trop/.style={very thick},scale=0.35]
    \draw[gray!40!] (-0.5,-0.5) grid (15.5,15.5);
    \draw[->,thick] (-.5,0)--(14.5,0);
    \draw[->,thick] (0,-.5)--(0,14.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{minipage}
      \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.2\linewidth} %inequalities
    \centering
    \begin{align*}
    &\text{1} & \max\{x_1,2\}   &\le 2+x_2\\
    &\text{2} & x_1         &\le \max\{2+x_2,4\}\\
    &\text{3} & x_1         &\le    \max\{-2+x_2,2\}\\
    &\text{4} & \max\{x_1,-1+x_2\}&\le 2
    \end{align*}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the `[t]` in front of the minipage into `[c]`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,leqno]{scrreprt} 
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h] 
    \begin{minipage}[c]{.2\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[trop/.style={very thick},scale=0.35]
    \draw[gray!40!] (-0.5,-0.5) grid (15.5,15.5);
    \draw[->,thick] (-.5,0)--(14.5,0);
    \draw[->,thick] (0,-.5)--(0,14.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{minipage}
      \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[c]{.2\linewidth} %inequalities
    \centering
    \begin{align*}
    &\text{1} & \max\{x_1,2\}   &\le 2+x_2\\
    &\text{2} & x_1         &\le \max\{2+x_2,4\}\\
    &\text{3} & x_1         &\le    \max\{-2+x_2,2\}\\
    &\text{4} & \max\{x_1,-1+x_2\}&\le 2
    \end{align*}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why .2\linewidth ? It should be .49\linewidth .

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need minipages (your code results in `\overfull\hbox` messages. A simple `\adjustbox{valign=c}` for the tikz picture, and the `aligned` environment will do. I also suggest another alignment for the equations:

```
\documentclass[11pt,leqno]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
 \hfill        
    \adjustbox{valign=c}{\begin{tikzpicture}[trop/.style={very thick},scale=0.35]
    \draw[gray!40!] (-0.5,-0.5) grid (15.5,15.5);
    \draw[->,thick] (-.5,0)--(14.5,0);
    \draw[->,thick] (0,-.5)--(0,14.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}}
      \hfill
    $ \begin{aligned}
    &\text{1} & & \max\{x_1,2\} \le 2+x_2\\
    &\text{2} & & x_1\le \max\{2+x_2,4\}\\
    &\text{3} & & x_1\le \max\{-2+x_2,2\}\\
    &\text{4} & & \max\{x_1,-1+x_2\}\le 2
    \end{aligned} $
    \hfill\null
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I get the following error: Undefinded control sequence. \adjustbox

Comment: @mabu: Sorry, I didn't check I forgot to load the `adjustbox` package (an extension of `graphicx`) in the code. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Set the baseline of the picture to the center:

```
\documentclass[11pt,leqno]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[trop/.style={very thick},scale=0.35,baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
  \draw[gray!40!] (-0.5,-0.5) grid (15.5,15.5);
  \draw[->,thick] (-.5,0)--(14.5,0);
  \draw[->,thick] (0,-.5)--(0,14.5);
\end{tikzpicture}\hfill
$\begin{aligned}
  &\text{1} & \max\{x_1,2\}   &\le 2+x_2\\
  &\text{2} & x_1         &\le \max\{2+x_2,4\}\\
  &\text{3} & x_1         &\le    \max\{-2+x_2,2\}\\
  &\text{4} & \max\{x_1,-1+x_2\}&\le 2
\end{aligned}$

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]